# Activate Feature in Powershell and specify custom properties

Tags: powershell, feature, feature-activation, properties, cmdlets

I want to activate a feature with custom properties. It is easy to do in onet.xml by providing Properties:

```
<Feature ID=“78277796-98D9-4276-B7D2-E3374AAC43D8“>
      <Properties>
            <Property Key=“MyProperty1“ Value=“FALSE“ />
            <Property Key=“MyProperty2“ Value=“6ECFC841-7FFF-4E06-9D50-0678CC43696D“ />
            <Property Key=“MyProperty3“ Value=“TRUE“ />
            <Property Key=“MyProperty4“ Value=“Custom Data“/>
      </Properties>
</Feature>
```

[In Code I have seen, we can use Reflection to specify custom properties](http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/07/15/specifying-properties-when-activating-features-through-code/) and [Yaroslavs remake](http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/12/02/activating-sharepoint-2010-features-with-properties/). How could one specify custom properties when activating feature in powershell:

```
Enable-SPFeature ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible throught Enable-SPFeature if you need it you'll have to write your own cmdlet, there a guide for doing that [here](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2009/10/creating-custom-sharepoint-2010-cmdlets-using-visual-studio-2010/)

In that cmdlet, you can use the reflection hack you linked to, but note that when you're using reflection to find non-public methods you run the risk of any update/hotfix/SP breaking your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you. It isn't reliable to use reflection because a new patch can change internal methods. But I was curious about creating cmdlets, so I created this one: [sp-lend-id.taprat](https://github.com/mirontoli/sp-lend-id/tree/master/taprat) The description is on my [blog](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/creating-custom-powershell-cmdlet/)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you have is a configurable component. If that is the case, you should implement configuration properly instead of hacking/reflecting an object to make is suit your purpose.

The patterns & practices group discusses configuration in "[The Application Setting Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798488.aspx)" section of their guidance. The guidance also includes sample code for a List-backed configuration store.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you provide an example how to implement the configuration "properly"?

Comment: Read content at the provided link.

Comment: Allright, one can do much with Application Settings Manager like [creating new configurations when activating feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798505.aspx) But how can we put properties into the feature when we enable it?